# Busybox httpd: error 501 on POST request and cgi not executing on yocto linux-3.10.53

Tags: linux, arm, webserver, busybox, yocto

I'm trying to set-up a lightweight web-server on a custom ARM-based board with linux 3.10.53 as OS. I've built the OS using the Yocto software.

I can see the html pages hosted on my board through the browser, though whenever I send an HTTP POST request I get as response the error "501 Not Implemented The requested method is not recognized".

Also when I send an HTTP GET request, the browser downloads the executable instead of running it. All the executables (that, as a test, only print plain strings in html fashion; source files are written in C code) are placed under the "cgi-bin" directory of the web-server home directory. I made sure to have changed their owner and permissions and, in fact, I can run them just fine from the board terminal.

Thanks for your help

editing here since i cannot check my answer as the correct one : Found the culprit: the httpd service build by busybox in the yocto software doesn't enable the cgi by default. I had to manually enable it, by using "bitbake busybox -c menuconfig" and checking the flag for cgi support in the "networking utilities" menu

Answer (score 1):

Found the culprit: the httpd service build by busybox in the yocto software doesn't enable the cgi by default. I had to manually enable it, by using "bitbake busybox -c menuconfig" and checking the flag for cgi support in the "networking utilities" menu